# How to add itemprop and assing a value to it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microdata

```
<h4 class="nobottommargin text-center keywords-data ng-scope">Keywords</h4>
```

What I want to do is add the item property `keywords` and assign a value to it for the above tag.

`$('.keywords-data').attr('itemprop','alternateName');`

With the above step,

```
<h4 class="nobottommargin text-center keywords-data ng-scope" itemprop="alternateName">Keywords</h4>
```

Now I want to add the value to `alternateName`, e.g.:

```
alternateName = 't1,t2';
```

Could you please provide me with suggestions on how to do this?

```
var keywordsData = 't1,t2';
$('.keywords-data').attr('itemprop','alternateName');
$('.keywords-data').attr('itemprop',keywordsData);
```

Comment: $('.keywords-data').attr('itemprop','t1,t2');

Comment: afetr adding the line still it was like  <h4 class="nobottommargin text-center keywords-data ng-scope"  itemprop="alternateName">Keywords</h4>

Comment: Could you please share the full code?

Comment: Rasel,edited my code.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rbatvjj4/. If it's not working for you there is an underlying issue you need to address. Check the console for errors

Comment: @nambu your code works just like you want. i agree with McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine. If you mean to change the value you can use

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7ka8jsp/2/)

```
$("[data-ref=alternateName]").html("test")
```